# Symfony doctrine:execute can't find Doctrine migrations in custom folder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony5, doctrine-migrations

We've set our configuration file for doctrine migrations as the following:

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'App\Migrations': "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations"
```

Our migrations command all work, for example, `doctrine:migrations:migrate` works, `doctrine:migrations:list` will list all the migrations in our /src/Migrations folder. However, we cannot execute the `doctrine:migrations:execute <versionNumber>` command because it will give an error that it cannot find the migration file: "Migration class "20220329211652" was not found?"

Does `doctrine:migrations:execute` not work for custom migration paths configuration? When placing these migrations back in the default folder, it works.

Comment: Putting the migrations in `App\Migrations` is [discouraged](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle/3.1/config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml) but maybe it's ok if you exclude them in `config/services.yaml`. Are you updating the namespace when moving the files? And IIRC, you should use the full classname: `bin/console d:m:m App\Migrations\Version20220329211652`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by using a fully qualified class name like:

```sh
bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute "App\Migrations\Version20220329211652"
```